# How change page URLs in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've used other CMS systems for years but new to WordPress. I need to change the URL (slug) of *many* pages and then fix any links to the page. e.g. A page was /about-company and noww we want it to /about

Two questions:

1. Bulk Change "Slugs" - Is there a way / plugin to change a large number of page slugs at once instead of having to do it manually? (e.g. specify them all in a CSV that some tool reads)
2. Update "Hrefs" - e.g. find all those "/about-company" links and change them to "/about". Again, very large site so this can't be a manually process of running a link checking and then having to manually run through and fix them. Again, is there a bulk approach where it will take our old slug to new slug, and rewrite "hrefs" throughout the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish each, by creating the CSVs with `from-what,to-what format` format, and use programming to traverse the Database and do search/replace automatically, but this will involve some coding + regex to catch all variants of what you need.

This is achievable with Bash,PHP,Python,or any language which can manipulate mysql records.

Comment: Programming something like this is our standard approach but with WP I'd hope a solution would exist. Yes of course it could be programmed, but is there an existing program? We'd want a way a non-programmer can do this.

Comment: Your question then needs more focus, as it does not show any coding issue you are trying to resolve, or attempted to solve yourself.